# How to access requested body from another function with async/await?

Tags: node.js, http, express, asynchronous, promise

sorry for the generic title. I'm pretty new to nodejs as well as the idea of async/await.

So I have an express app, which makes an HTTP get request as a callback function. The callback function gets the body object, and returns it to getBody function. But when I try to assign getBody to a variable, it returns undefined.

Yes I know. The getBody function returns body before body gets filled up with data, but I just don't know how to write a getter method for this body object. So my question is, how can I run the get request and access body object in the global scope at the same time, so all functions depending on body object can run without further problems.

```
async function getBody (req, res, next) {
    let body = await makeRequest(req, res);
    return body; // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED

}

router.get('/', getBody);

function makeRequest (req, res){

    let uri;

    let options = {
        uri: uri,
    };

    request(options,  function (error, response, body) {
        if (error){
            console.log('error:', error);
        } else {
            console.log('Success! statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
            let jsonObject =  JSON.parse(body);

            return jsonObject;
        }
    });
}
```

I did my research, but I just could not find a useful resource. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to return a Promise from makeRequest [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` and `async` should be used with a promise, these kind of method cannot return data. `return` is used to return a value from a synchronous method.

So you may return a promise from your `makeRequest` method like this,

```
async function getBody(req, res, next) {
    let body = await makeRequest(req, res);
    return body; // NOW BODY IS NOT UNDEFINED, call next() or send response here
}

router.get('/', getBody);

function makeRequest(req, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let uri;

        let options = {
            uri: uri,
        };

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('error:', error);
                return reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Success! statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
                let jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);

                return resolve(jsonObject);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

FYI,

```
let body = await makeRequest(req, next)
```

is equals to

```
makeRequest(req, next).then(body => { /* YOUR CODE HERE */ })
```

and if you didn't knew, you have to process the body and send the response, `return body` won't send the response to the client.

Comment: While you're correct about needing a Promise for async/await to work, getBody makes no sense in this context as a route handler as neither it nor makerequest actually respond to the request nor call next()

Comment: That's correct, I saw that too. But I just answered the question he asked.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. As @Paul pointed out getBody makes no sense as a route handler, but I don't even want to send the body to a view. I want to extract information from body. What is the convention for this? Should I use another middleware where I can call functions on body? 
Another clunky question: how can I access the body from another file?

Comment: You can't access the body from another file, you may pass the body to another function and make sure at least you send a empty response  `res.json({})` otherwise your client will hang

Answer (score 2):

OK, @JanithKasun did a great job of answering your original question fully.  This answer is intended to expand on that a little to get a the problem you're having conceptually that isn't explicitly asked in your question.

As I understand your code, you're trying to fetch some data from a third party resource based on information in the request coming to your app's handler.  Ideally, you want to separate your code in a way to make it more reusable/maintainable.  I note that the code in question doesn't actually use the request or response object *at all*, but I'm going to assume you would have some kind of parameter to the getBody function that helps you construct the URI it's requesting.  So, to that end:

```
// ./lib/get-body.js
const BASE_URI = 'https://example.com/search?q='
async function getBody (query) {
    let body = await makeRequest(query);
    return body;
}

function makeRequest(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let uri = `${BASE_URI}{query}`; // results in something like 'https://example.com/search?q=cats'

        let options = {
            uri: uri,
        };

        // Note: removed console statements here to centralize error handling
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            } else {
                let jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);
                return resolve(jsonObject);
            }
        });
    })
}
// export the top level function for reuse
module.exports = getBody;
```

Now, in your routing code:

```
// ./index.js or wherever
const express = require('express');
const getBody = require('./lib/get-body');

//...whatever other setup...

app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const query = req.query.terms; // or whatever
    try {
      const body = await getBody(query);
      return res.send(body);
    } catch (e) {
        return next(e); // if you don't do this, process hangs forever on error
    }
});

// handle the errors. obviously you can do something smart like 
//  figure out the error code and send back something other than a 500 if appropriate. 
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).send('I am Bender; please insert girder.');
});
```

Hope that helps!